# Deriving information from hex string

Tags: java, c#, hex

I have a database for a video game and I store the video game items in a varbinary(3792) column. I'm trying to make a program to edit and create items which are in the form of a 32-length hex string. It's fairly easy to create the items as I know what each of the positions in the hex string represent in terms of the items properties however my issue is taking a hex string and deriving the items properties from it since some of the properies share the same position in the hex string..

Consider the following hex string:

index: 012345...
hex:   0000120B837A00000010000000000000

My problem is I have 3 different properties: Level, Luck and Skill.

Luck is a boolean and adds 4 to position 3 or is otherwise 0.

Skill is a boolean and adds 8 to position 2 or is otherwise 0.

Level is a int and uses position 2 and 3. Adds 8 each time.

Example position 2,3 could be: FC

=> Level 15 (8*15 = 120 to pos 2,3) + skill (8 to pos 2) + luck (4 to pos 3)

So my question is, given a hex string and looking at positions 2,3 how could I possibly know which properties are contained when multiple properties use the same positions? I am new to hex/binary systems so I apologize if I've missed out some information. I am also trying to achieve this in C# or Java.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use additional columns in the database table to help you with your calculations? Each time the values are edited, you can use counters for Level, Skill and Luck, and easily locate each amount in the hex value.

Comment: The database design is not mine which the game uses so I couldn't change the design in anyway without dramatically changing the games code which I don't have access to. I'm just trying to make a program to edit and create theses items.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do a bit of binary math.  It's easier to use java `BigInteger` for this rather than a hex string.  Assuming you are counting position from the left and start counting with 1:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "0FC0120B837A00000010000000000000"; // FC in pos 2,3
    BigInteger num = new BigInteger(s, 16);

    int level = num.shiftRight(29*4+3).intValue() & 0b1111;
    int luck  = num.shiftRight(29*4+2).intValue() & 1;
    int skill = num.shiftRight(30*4+3).intValue() & 1;

    System.out.printf("level: %s, luck: %s, skill: %s%n", level, luck, skill);
}
```

Let's take one of these apart:

`int level = num.shiftRight(29*4+3).intValue() & 0b1111;`

- `29` is the 0 based position for level from the right (32 - 3 = **29**)
- `4` is the number of bits in 1 hex digit
- `3` is the number of offset bits within the position for this field.  level is multiplied by 8 and 8 = 2 ^ **3**, so the offset is 3 bits.
- `0b1111` is the mask representing how many bits go into this variable.  Since level is stored as 4 bits (0-15), the mask is `0b1111`.  We could represent the same number as `(1 << 4) - 1` where 4 is the number of bits.